# “Realname” module is not creating “pretty URLs” for new users?

Tags: 7, uri, cron, users

I’m working on a site which I’ve taken over the development from a former employee. He has installed the module **realname** which, as I understand, should enable the function that a user URL is not the cryptic ID but the users first+last name, so the URL might look something like this:   www.mydomain.com/user/firstname-lastname

It work for most of the users but I’ve discovered that some of the users (especially new users) still uses the ID in the URL, so it become something like www.mydomain.com/user/eyyrdctxeec and that mess a lot of things up.

I’m suspecting that it might has something to do with the module and it only “recalculate” the names in some time interval, maybe by the CRON jobs. But I want it to create that member URL when a new user has signed up to the page.

Has anyone experienced that before and might have a solution? As I said, it isn’t me that has initially created this site so I don’t have a clear overview if the original developer have done some customization or other configuration – I’ve search to solve the problem but with no luck.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 5, accepted):

congratulations on inheriting someone else's work, it was really well documented, right? ;-)

All joking aside, the [realname](http://drupal.org/project/realname) module is used to display alternate names instead of the username.

To get the /user/firstname-lastname urls you would use the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and configure the "pattern" accordingly. Instead of "user/..." you might want to use the "member/..." to keep things a bit separated. I bet pathauto is already used on your site.

Just change the pattern, delete all user paths and re-create them in a batch.

I also suggest you check all the additionally installed modules and read up on what they are supposed to do. No worries, you'll learn quickly, just use this site a lot. And try to improve your "accept rate" a bit to get more answers ;-)

Comment: Hi MotoTribe, thank you very much for your answer. You are absolutely correct, the documentation is near to nothing..

The pathauto module was correctly installed and I tried to follow your steps and well, it work but, there still is some users which hasn't got a correct "ID". And this is where I might think the realname module is to blame.

The pattern in pathauto is: **member/[realname]** and I guess that it is the token [realname] which is wrong in some of the cases. Do you have any comments on that? 
And thanks for your encouragement. I'm convinced that this site will come to great use :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how pathauto will deal with duplicate realnames, maybe that's what causing the issue? I would use member/[username] because it's unique by default. I also added some extra validation to my signup to not allow spaces and other "funny" characters in the username because they might break your url.